# Any way to play Windows Games on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, games

I was wondering if I can play Windows Games on Ubuntu through software so I can play games like Wildstar (MMO), Steam/Origin Games etc.

Personally I don't want to use Windows, I've always disliked it but to play the latest games you need it so I've always felt "forced" so to speak.

Thank you in advance

Dean

Comment: Welcome to [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/). It is advice to search the solution/answer before asking a new question. Did you ever try to find the answer, before asking? You would have got hundreds of answers in this forum itself..

Answer (score 0):

You could always cheat and use the software 'VirtualBox' and create a Windows VM?